# SCP : Failed to download a file from a VM in Azure

Tags: azure, ssh, neo4j, scp

I have an Azure Virtual Machine containing a query.log file (this a VM containing Neo4j community edition). I would like to download this file on my local computer. I tried this:

```
PS C:\Users\surname.name> scp -vvv azureuser@ip_vm:/var/log/neo4j/query.log C:\surname.name\Downloads
Executing: program ssh.exe host ip_vm, user azureuser, command scp -v -f /var/log/neo4j/query.log
OpenSSH_for_Windows_8.1p1, LibreSSL 3.0.2
debug3: Failed to open file:C:/Users/surname.name/.ssh/config error:2
debug3: Failed to open file:C:/ProgramData/ssh/ssh_config error:2
debug2: resolve_canonicalize: hostname ip_vm is address
debug2: ssh_connect_direct
debug1: Connecting to ip_vm [ip_vm] port 22.
debug3: finish_connect - ERROR: async io completed with error: 10060, io:...
debug1: connect to address ip_vm port 22: Connection timed out
ssh: connect to host ip_vm port 22: Connection timed out
```

But I don't know where I'm wrong. I have no problem to ssh the VM

Answer (score 0):

A error like that suggests (as in [this thread](https://www.linode.com/community/questions/19682/unable-to-ssh-from-private-ip)) that something (policy, firewall) is blocking SSH inbound traffic.

Outgoing SSH seems allows, since an `ssh azureuser@ip_vm` is working.